The margin from the parent VF page is repeating on the child VF page
"Despite setting the margin-top to 0px in the child Visualforce page CSS, the margin from the parent Visualforce page is still being applied
I have specific content in the parent header, so I need the margin to be 400px. However, in the child page, I only need a margin of 50px to display the logo.
Parent VF Page
<apex:page >
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin-top: 400px;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        @top-left {
            content: element(header);
        }
        @bottom-center {
            content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
    }

    div.header {
        position: running(header);
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
<!-- Include another Visualforce page with custom CSS applied -->
<div style="overflow: auto; margin-top: 0px !important;">
    <apex:include pageName="ASPOPDFTermsAndConditions"/>
</div>
</apex:page>

Child Vf page:
<apex:page >
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        @top-left {
            content: element(header);
        }
    }
</style>````
</apex:page>
Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance."

